# UX Gamification: Achievements, Medals, Badges, or Trophies?

Tags: gui-design, user-research, mobile-application, gamification, user-engagement

I am a developer in an upcoming **Social Media App** project, and within my application, I have incorporated a points and reward system to increase user retention and engagement. I'm stuck between these terms to define an "**Achievement**" or "**Reaching a Goal**" within the app. These items are awarded and kept by the user, and they can can share and view them any time:

- Achievement
- Medal
- Badge
- Trophy

**Psychologically**, which do you feel gives off a larger reward satisfaction, a greater sense of accomplishment, in your own opinion? :)

Thanks, excited to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the concept of gamification is closely tied with the concept of ***relative difference.***

When I say "I have 100 medals", out-of-context it means nothing. But when I say "I have 100 medals while my friend just has 10" well that changes the whole concept.

There are leaderboards for a reason. You always want to keep competing for the top position and share it on social media to brag about it.

Out of the options you listed, **Achievements** as such is intangible and should be avoided. **Badges** and **Medals** are found in abundance in real world  and we connect them with multiple numbers instantly while **Trophies** seems more exclusive.

I hope I was of help!

Comment: Thats an excellent point you made there, very in-depth. I'll keep all that in mind! Thank you :)